# Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing

Tags: apt, package-management

While using the command

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I lost my internet. When I again used the command

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I got the following error:

```
Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing
```

What to do? I am using 14.04 version.

Comment: Do: `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: i have done sudo apt-get update , and it worked fine  , upgrade has stopped working

Answer (score 5):

What happened when you tried:

```
sudo  apt-get update
```

Have you also tried:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing
```

It seems like it is trying to tell you how to fix the problem.  Don't be afraid to give it a try.  If it doesn't work, come back.

Comment: hey i restarted my system then used sudo apt-get update (worked fine) and then used sudo apt-get upgrade and this time it worked again , ,,, thank you :)

Comment: Just glad you found something that worked.  No worries.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!